# Searching for a way to programmatically receive messages with the ChatConnector

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am currently working with the Microsoft Bot Framework in NodeJS.
I am using a ChatConnector for receiving the input messages and here is my question:

Is there a way to let the connector receive a message programmatically?

The reason why I want this is a forwarding the last message in chat.
I need a line which fakes a user input in the chat.

Thanks for any suggestions.

[image]

For example the bot finished a dialog in "mainListen". As a result the user types for example "thanks and now do this". The input is in the message.text as a result available in the first "initStuff". Now i want to be able to use the message input as a input for the mainListen. At this point the user needs to tpye in the commands twice. The "mainListen" is for language understanding to lead into some other dialogs.

Comment: Question is a little bit unclear. Do you want to receive message from User A and send it to User B?

Comment: Sorry my friend. So in this case iam ending my main dialog with a result - just a message text. The bot is rejoining at the "/" root dialog and iam able to get the last message. The problem is i need to paste the last message two times because the bot does not react to the last input. To prevent this i want to fake the input for the ChatConnector with the result message to fluently lead into the first dialog again.

Comment: Post your code please otherwise it will be hard to hep you.